# Enter a text in input box in IE 11 using protractor

Tags: internet-explorer, protractor, sendkeys

Currently what I'm doing is I'm trying to enter a text into a input box (IE 11) using protractor but it happen an error.
This is the error that I get:

```
IE sanity spec
  - Failed: sendKeysToActiveElement
```

Because my code is:

```
element.sendKeys("ohio usa");
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

I am using keys to press enter as well.

Comment: Add screen prints to give more clarity on the issue and clearly mention the objectives you want to achieve.

Comment: @madhan I have already written the code, I am trying to sendkeys "abc" to input box and then I am pressing enter using protractor.key.enter, which is not working in IE.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do browser.actions(). 
Just use the element:

```
element.sendKeys("ohio usa"); 
element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```